# this.currentView in BackboneJS is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am rendering subview in main view in Backbone.js In order to kill zoombie view I create a public function :

```
function showView(view) {
  if (view){
    view.remove();
  }
  this.currentView = view;
  this.currentView.render();
  $("#column").html(this.currentView.el);
}
```

Here I call `showView()`:

```
 render : function(){
        this.$el.html(mainTemplate);
        var _subview= new SubView({el : '#column'});
        showView(_subview);
 }
```

Subview :

```
define(["jquery" ,
"underscore" ,
"backbone",
"text!templates/subviewTemplate.html"
],function($, _, Backbone, Subview){
 var SubView= Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){

    },
    render: function(){
        var _subview= _.template(Subview);
        this.$el.html(_subview());
        return this;
    }
 });
 return SubView;
});
```

Problem : When I do `console.log(this.currentView)` in my current view or in `showView()`, the result is undefined.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: why are you passing Subview to the undescore template function?

Comment: @kinakuta : Oh it is just a html template name, not a view.

Comment: Is that your actual code? _.template, with just one parameter, will return a function. Could you either make a jsfiddle or include more of your code?

Comment: @kinakuta I've added full code in Subview block of my question. Please kindly have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things: first, underscore's _.template function, unless you pass it both a template and some data, is returning another function. Right now it appears you're just passing it the template string. You either need to additionally pass it the data to interpolate:

```
var _subview = _.template(Subview, { key: value });
```

Or, if there is no data to interpolate, you need to invoke the method to return the markup string:

```
$(this.el).html(_subview());
```

The other thing I recommend, if you're going to attach your views to existing elements, is not to use this.$el. When the element you're asking it to attach to isn't in the DOM yet, this.$el will be undefined. Instead of using this shorthand, you can still do $(this.el) because it won't try to select and cache the el as a jquery wrapped object before the element exists in the DOM. The other alternative is to allow your divs to create the element and you append the entire el into the DOM, in which case you can use this.$el in your render method.

Comment: I changed from `this.$el.html(_subview);` to `$(this.el).html(_subview());`, but `console.log(this.currentView)` is still undefined.

Comment: where are you logging it? is view defined when passed into showView? also, are you attaching the parent view by specifying el at instantiation? if so, you should make the same change in that view's render call

Comment: I am logging it in `showView` function. View is defined correctly in `showView`. I am attaching sub view to parent view >> `var _subview= new SubView({el : '#column'}); showView(_subview);`.

Comment: logging it where? if view is defined, then it doesn't follow that this.currentView isn't defined after assigning view to it

Comment: I'm logging it `showView()` (`function showView(view) { console.log(view); console.log(this.currentView);`)

Comment: if you're logging it before you've assigned view to it, it should be undefined - showView is a global function, and 'this' inside that function is the global object - currentView is simply a property of the global object and it will be undefined until you assign something to it, in this case, view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61884/discussion-between-nothing-and-kinakuta).